# Same links in different WooCommerce categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm sorry for my question, but I couldn't find an answer.

I have several WooCommerce categories and subcategories:

```
/new-york/apartments
/paris/apartments
/madrid/elite/apartments
```

It is very important that the subcategories have the same names in the links.

I understand that the WordPress structure does not allow such links and adds the name of the previous category:

```
/madrid/elite/apartments-elite
```

But maybe there's some way to fix it? It's very necessary.

Thank you so much in advance!

**P.S. May be, could it be done with redirects?**

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what u're trying to do, what exactly is the categories structure and which exact link you want to get out of that structure? That's the starting point

Comment: I need WordPress to not add parent category names to child categories.

Comment: Well if all your parent categories have a child named "apartments" and you want all of them with the same url, how is wordpress supposed to understand which one of the child elements to show? this kinda puzzle me. You need to keep something, either the parent cat name or the childs cat can't be all the same

Comment: I understand that the current WordPress link structure does not allow me to do what I want. So I wrote here. Maybe can do it with redirects or something?

Comment: I just found this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6106/remove-parent-category-from-permalink-basically-only-have-the-child-category but it should be for normal WP cat and not Woocommerce categories. Anyways, i can't even reproduce to have multiple subcategories with the same slug, even if in different parents. One of the two must have a different slug. How did u inserted those?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't fit. Especially since it was nine years ago.

Comment: It's impossible to do such a categorization, keep in mind that WP make it impossible for a reason. So if you have 2 main categories "/new-york/apartments" & 
"/paris/apartments" with the same subcategory "apartments" what do you think woo will display if you try to display the products under "apartments"???? it will show both apartments under "new-york" and "paris"!! Understand now?

Comment: I believe what you want is not what's you're looking for here. Also why you don't do the following. Create a category named "new-york" and another category name "new-york-apartments" and add the product to both of them. I feel this is the best solution you can get.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I know the WordPress link structure very well. And I could easily do as you wrote, but I need this particular link structure for the project. 
Unfortunately, in seven days, no one could help me (((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're categorising your pages in the wrong manner.

You should have a category called Appartments and inside that category have pages, products subcats for the location.

e.g. apartments/new-york/

That way you have the main page called apartments as you want. With the ability to then select a location.

But to be honest it looks like you should be using tags. Tags allow multiple selections. For instance, you could have a tag for new york and a tag for apartments. So then you just have a page that calls new-york apartments or whatever tag selections you need.

[Woocomerce Product Tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-product-taxonomies/#section-3)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've been thinking about it. It's not exactly what it takes, but there's no better option yet (((

Comment: For example, if make several real estate options in New York, you will still have problems with the same category /new-york ((

Comment: That's where tags won't have that issue though. Don't use categories at all just use Tag's